# Which UPS, for home use, which can automatically shutdown the PC when battery is low?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ups

I am planning to build a single server machine which is highly dependent on data residing in RAM for performance reasons. I am looking for a UPS which can power the PC during a blackout (very rare) and when the battery level is like %20, it sends a signal to Windows 2008 to shutdown. Even if it's only for a few minutes, that's good enough. This is for home use so I am looking for an inexpensive unit ( less than $300? ).

Which brand/model is good choice? I prefer one whose battery is easily & cheaply replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Any UPS that comes with an appropriate connection and compatible software should meet your needs. I've had both Tripp Lite and APC myself.

Comment: Same here. Good experiences with APC SmartUPS, both onder Linux and Windows.